# differentiable function with only positive/negative slope impies strictly increasing/decreasing

Tags: functions, derivatives, first-order-logic

> If $f:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ is differentiable and
>
> 1.$f'(x)>0$ for all x $\in (a,b)$.
>
> $\ \ $then $f$ is strictly increasing on (a,b).
>
> 2.Similarly, if $f'(x)<0$ for all x $\in (a,b)$, then $f$ is strictly decreasing on (a,b)

---

Proof.(1.)

Assume $f:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ is differentiable

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ and $f'(x)>0$ for all x $\in (a,b)$

Show that $\forall x_1,x_2 \in (a,b),x_1<x_2\rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2)$

Since $\exists x_3 \in (a,b) s.t. \forall x \in (a,b),0<f'(x_3)\leq f'(x)$

We can conclude that

$\exists x_3 \in (a,b) s.t. \forall x_1,x_2 \in (a,b),x_1<x_2 \rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_1)+f'(x_3)(x_2-x_1)\leq f(x_2)$

Therefore, $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$

Proof.(2.)

Similar to (1.)

---

Questions:

1.Is my proof right?

2.Any other ways to prove this?

Thanks:)

Comment: The statement $\exists x_3 \in (a,b) s.t. \forall x \in (a,b),0<f'(x_3)<f'(x)$ is totally unjustified (and in fact, wrong).

Comment: It is also totally unclear how you reached the conclusion that $\exists x_3 \in (a,b) s.t. \forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbf{R},x_1<x_2 \rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_1)+f'(x_3)(x_2-x_1)\leq f(x_2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a "hint". Pick any $x_1, x_2 \in (a,b)$ such that $x_1 < x_2$. By the mean value theorem, there's a $c \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that
\begin{equation}
f'(c) = \dfrac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}
\end{equation}
I'll leave it to you to write and finish up the proof properly.

Comment: Yes, that's so true. Otherwise, it would be contradiction. thanks